# Custom taxonomy shows full articles

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

I have created some custom taxonomies in the function.php. Once a user selects a taxonomy the site displays a list with all full articles related to the custom taxonomy.

**How can I display only the Title of the articles once a user selects a custom taxonomy?**

Answer (score 0):

In the Wordpress Loop all you have to do is show the title only

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of something like this. There is not something like: if($taxonomy){  loop through posts  }. How do I know when a user has selected a taxonomy (and expects a list with the related content)?